# Nameserver inside local network is not working

Tags: dns, bind

I have a problem when I want to host my nameserver inside local network.

I have a registered domain (example.com).

I want to host the nameserver of "local.example.com" inside my local network.

I want The nameserver in my local network to define the records for "local.example.com".

I set The NS record for the "local.example.com" to "ns-local.example.com".

The IP of "ns-local.example.com" is "192.168.1.243".

I defined The NS record of local.example.com in the public DNS of the domain "example.com" like the follwoing:

local IN NS ns-local.example.com.

ns-local IN A 192.168.1.243

We have a separated recursive DNS server in our LAN, which we can not use for any authoritative DNS server.

I Set the A record for local.example.com in "ns-local.example.com" to "192.168.1.10".

When I ping the local.example.com, it resolves to 67.215.66.132 (servfail.guide.opendns.com)!!!!

When I run the command "dig local.example.com +trace" inside my local network I get the correct result ("192.168.1.10" for A record).

All nameservers use BIND.

thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So performing `dig local.example.com +trace` bypasses your internal recursive DNS server completely.

What response do you get when you just run `dig local.example.com` (this will use your internal DNS server)?

Comment: So you shouldn't get this response, your own zone should provide the response not opendns.com, what response do you get with `dig local.example.com ns`? Please paste the full dig response so I can see the various flags etc.

Comment: Actually, it could be your forwarders to OpenDNS which are causing the problem, do you really need to forward to OpenDNS? why not let BIND handle the recursive DNS itself? Anyway, try adding an empty forwarders clause into the local.example.com zone construct `forwarders { };` and see if that stops the local nameserver from forwarding the query up the chain.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Adding an empty forwarders clause into the local.example.com zone construct works. Thank you so much for your help.